# Can't make random div visible

Tags: javascript

I have a array named compliments with my IDs in it, and I try to make a random ID visible but it won't work

```
var compliments=new Array()

compliments[0]="divid"

compliments[1]="divid2"

compliments[2]="divid"

compliments[3]="divid2"

compliments[4]="divid"

compliments[5]="divid2"

compliments[6]="divid" 
document.getElementById(compliments[Math.round(Math.random()*compliments.length-1)).style.visibility ="visible";
```

Comment: You are missing the closing ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var compliments = ["divid", "divid2", "divid", "divid2", "divid", "divid2", "divid"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * compliments.length);
var div = document.getElementById(compliments[random]);
div.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket is not closed in your code.

```
compliments[Math.round(Math.random()*compliments.length-1)]
```

```js
var compliments=new Array()

compliments[0]="divid"

compliments[1]="divid2"

compliments[2]="divid"

compliments[3]="divid2"

compliments[4]="divid"

compliments[5]="divid2"

compliments[6]="divid" 


document.getElementById(compliments[Math.round(Math.random()*compliments.length-1)]).style.visibility ="visible";
```

```html
<div id="divid" style="visibility: hidden;">Test1</div>
<div id="divid2" style="visibility: hidden;">Test2</div>
```